# How to clip/crop an image with AsciiDoctor

Tags: asciidoctor

Is there some way (besides writing a plugin) to clip/crop an image which is inserted into an AsciiDoc document?

I couldn't find such a feature in the docs but there might be a plugin I am not aware of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such feature. When you use the `image:` macro, you can set the image's width and height, but there is no option to set the crop area or starting point for cropping. See https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#images for details.

To crop the images, you might need to perform some sort of pre/post processing to directly crop the images. Unless you have a requirement to dynamically crop the image, it's probably best to do so manually.

If you do need the ability to dynamically crop images, you might create a plugin that creates a new macro, say `crop:`, that uses the `image:` macro's internals, but accepts crop coordinates and performs the cropping on the source image.